# Затемнение Activity в фоне

Tags: android

У меня из **Activity-A** открывается **Activity-B**, при этом **A** не закрывается. При закрытии **B** существует небольшая стандартная анимация её скатывания вниз. Как сделать, чтобы при этом скатывании **Activity-B**, **Activity-A** имела небольшое затемнение, которое постепенно пропадает вплоть до окончания анимации.

Нужное затемнение по стандарту существует у DrawerLayout при его открытии/закрытии, вот такой же результат мне и нужен.

Comment: Используйте фрагменты и анимацию

Comment: Гайд по анимациям перехода между ативити. https://dimlix-com.turbopages.org/dimlix.com/s/animated-transition-android/ . Вам нужно видимо при анимации манипулировать альфа-каналом цвета.